# SMTPAuthenticationError Pythonanywhere

Tags: python, python-3.x, pythonanywhere

For a few times my contact website isn't working anymore. I make it work in local and made the same change on my server but it still doesn't work. My website is host by python anywhere. Here is my code to send the mail.

```
@app.route('/sendMail', methods=['POST']) def send():
    fromaddr = str(request.form['author'])
    toaddr = "*****@gmail.com"
    message = fromaddr + "\n" + str(request.form['message'])
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = fromaddr
    msg['To'] = toaddr
    msg['Subject'] = request.form['subject']
    msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
    #server.starttls()
    server.login(toaddr, setting.PASSWORD)
    text = msg.as_string()
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
    server.quit()
    return render_template('contact.html')
```

Do you have any idea about the problem?
It's a Flask project and I'm using python 3.

Comment: what's the error traceback in your error log on PythonAnywhere when it doesn't work?

Comment: smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (534, b'5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbu8\n5.7.14 MxtnCixxrcWybjoMdLBY7JkSxpsQbg5XvdMmFzU1YDyUz-i8vxJmN2QOn6WL7H1SMOjZEc\n5.7.14 ps8GtZiUgHqaprbgWjkWClRNThmphcSOmlo3zxJfwvfA1NKavpi_EqznNs_I8zwJd67QM9\n5.7.14 Qignop1Y3e5p1GtKczNB0t1-slEwslDEGBxeeWARWyEviZ3id9N_fTmrpRjnHm2nT3hxIL\n5.7.14 ro3AKRmC95b5fLHm7mDxo_q5mBjvPpWFlX6j0XN6h2zulAws4e> Please log in via\n5.7.14 your web browser and then try again.\n5.7.14  Learn more at\n5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 y143-v6sm13737713qky.95 - gsmtp')

Comment: Are you using an app-specific password?   Google tends to be more suspicious of logins from cloud services like PythonAnywhere, especially if they use the main account password.   App-specific passwords are separate passwords for your Gmail account that can be used by automated stuff like scripts.   If you search on Google you can find out how to set one up.

Comment: Are you using an app-specific password?   Google tends to be more suspicious of logins from cloud services like PythonAnywhere, especially if they use the main account password.   App-specific passwords are separate passwords for your Gmail account that can be used by automated stuff like scripts.   If you search on Google you can find out how to set one up.

Comment: Yes I did add an app-specific password and now it's working. Thanks for your help.